# How do I check if a element is contained within a list?

Tags: erl

How can I catch word from list and return `True` in Erlang?

```
catch_word(msg) ->
    Bad = ["BadWord1", "BadWord2"],
    case Bad in msg of
        true ->
            true;
        false ->
            false
    end.

catch_word("Hello, How are u BadWord1").
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Erlang, you may want to try this:

```
-export([catch_word/2]).

catch_word(Msg,BadWords)->
    catch_word(Msg,BadWords,0).

catch_word(Msg,[],0)->
    false;
catch_word(Msg,[Word|BadWords],0)->
        catch_word(Msg,BadWords,string:str(Msg,Word));
catch_word(_,_,N)->
    true.
```

and

```
your_module:catch_word("Hello, How are u BadWord1",["BadWord1", "BadWord2"]).
```